# finding an unknown constant of a pdf

Tags: probability-theory

I am revising for an exam and have come across a question which involves some partilculary hard integration!

$\int{\frac{C(ln x)^{n-1}}{x^3}}$, $y \in \mathbb R $, $x \ge 1$

Find C

So i know that as this is a pdf, and hence $\int{f_x(x)dx}=1$

so i have put 
$\int{\frac{C(ln x)^{n-1}}{x^3}} = 1 $ but i am struggling with the integration!

After a long page of integration i have got $C= {\frac{2^n}{(n-1)!}}$

Could someone please tell me if this is correct?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You did not specify the $x$ for which the given function is the density function. Is it $1$ to $\infty$? Or something else?

Comment: sorry forgot to write it! yes that is correct!

Comment: Yes, the integral does not take long if you look up the definition of the gamma function.

Comment: i have been looking it up all evening! i think  got it right tho so all okay. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. I hope the brief answer below is enough. You may already be familiar with the [Gamma Function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Answer (score 0):

Make the substitution $u=\ln x$. Then $du=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$, so $dx=e^u\,du$. Substituting, we find that we want to choose $C$ so that 
$$\int_0^\infty Cu^{n-1}e^{-2u}\,du=1.$$
To evaluate $\int_0^\infty u^{n-1}e^{-2u}\,du$, first let $2u=t$. The integral is then 
$$\frac{1}{2^n}\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}\,dt.$$
The integral $\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}\,dt$ a standard one, it has value  $\Gamma(n)$, which is $(n-1)!$  if $n$ is an integer.

Thus our original integral has value $C\frac{(n-1)!}{2^n}$, so $C=\frac{2^n}{(n-1)!}$.